# UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause not doing anything

Tags: ios, objective-c, remote-control, uievent

I have an application that plays music and want to use lockscreen control (play/pause).
With NSLog I can see that my app get's the button trigger but not theUIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause.

Here's a bit of my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}

- (void)remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:(UIEvent *)receivedEvent
{
    NSLog(@"REMOTE RECEIVE");
    if (receivedEvent.type == UIEventTypeRemoteControl)
    {
        NSLog(@"received remote event");
        switch (receivedEvent.subtype)
        {
            case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause:
                NSLog(@"toggle button received");
                //[self togglePlayPauseTapped: nil];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

I get "REMOTE RECEIVE" and "received remote event" from the NSLog Output but not the line inside ...TogglePlayPause.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use the case

> UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPause
>
> UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPlay

for iOS 7

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is *not* clear.

`UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPlay`, `UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPause` and `UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlStop` are called within the **user interaction**.

`UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause` is called within **headset interaction**.